# Interval inside iframe load function counts twice and unable to stop

Tags: jquery, iframe, load, setinterval, clearinterval

I have a page that loads another website in an iframe.
The problem now is that I need to log if the top window is blurred and if so a counter needs to be stopped. When you click in the iframe this window will get focused and after hovering out I can not get the focus back to the top window. So when I would click an other tab in my browser it does not call the actual blur function for this window.
What I need is a way to give the original focus back to the top window after the iframe was clicked and the cursor has moved back out of the iframe with a mouseleave.

I tried several ways to do something like this that I found on stackoverflow but nothing suits me.

It should look something like this:

```
$('iframe').mouseleave(function()
{
    $(window.top).focus();
});
$(window).blur(function()
{
    console.log('window blur'); 
});
```

**EDIT WORKAROUND BUT clearInterval not working now:**

Because I did not got answers for the above code I tried something different which worked.
I did a check on the body and when the mouse leaves it stopped the interval. This was enough for me. But because it also would be nice to start the counter when the iframe has loaded I tried to put the interval inside the `$('iframe').load` function. But what happens is that the inteval will count two times. When you want an interval with 1 seconds it does 2 seconds. And now when the mouse leaves the body it will not stop the interval but set it back to 1 seconds instead of stopping it. Below the code:

```
var $interval = '';
$('body').mouseleave(function()
{
    clearInterval($interval);
    $('.message').html('<div class="alert alert-error"><button type="button" class="close" onclick="javascript:window.opener=\'x\';window.close();">×</button>You may not navigate away from advertisements! Click <a href="">here</a> to try again.</div>');
});
$("iframe").load(function()
{
    $interval = setInterval(function()
    {
        clearInterval($interval);
        console.log('clear interval not working when inside iframe load function');
    }, 1000);
});
```

Hope someone knows what is going on here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing:

```
$("iframe").load(function()
```

for:

```
document.getElementById("website").onload = function()
```

Did the trick.

*Still don't know why the load function called the inside interval twice for each interval. If someone could explain this it would be nice. Thanks anyway.*

**EDIT:**

I think I know why it loops the interval twice. Each time you click a link inside the iframe (the website thats been loaded) The function captures this as a page load. What I did to prevent this is added a class to the body on the first time the iframe loads like "iframe_loaded" and after a user clicks a link inside the iframe it will first check if the body already has this class and if so it will not output the interval function a second time.